# Interactive HTML underlay with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

Can we make the following Google Map interactive provided the frame image is showing.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" onclick="$('#frame_image').show();" value="Show frame layer">
<input type="button" onclick="$('#frame_image').hide();" value="Hide frame layer">
<br /><br />

<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
    <iframe frameborder="0" width="358" height="358" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="https://maps.google.ca/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=55+Avenue+Road,++Toronto,+Ontario+M5R+3L2+Canada&amp;aq=&amp;sll=43.656877,-79.32085&amp;sspn=0.852471,2.113495&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=55+Avenue+Rd,+Toronto,+Ontario+M5R+1C6&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=43.67111,-79.395217&amp;output=embed&iwloc=near" ></iframe>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
    <small><a href="https://maps.google.ca/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=55+Avenue+Road,++Toronto,+Ontario+M5R+3L2+Canada&amp;aq=&amp;sll=43.656877,-79.32085&amp;sspn=0.852471,2.113495&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=55+Avenue+Rd,+Toronto,+Ontario+M5R+1C6&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=43.67111,-79.395217" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left" target="_blank">View Larger Map</a></small>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; color:red; z-index: 2" id="frame_image">
    <img src="http://torontoclinic.awkwardhosting.com/images/frame.gif" />
</div>
```

Code is also on the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/pPrZV/

Please let me know if there is any other way via Google Maps API etc.
Thanks

Comment: You can try putting it on the map using Google Maps API as another Custom Overlay ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays ) instead putting overlying img.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply this style to `<iframe>` of the google map

`<iframe` **style="border-radius:250px"** `frameborder="0" width="358" height="358" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"...`

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pPrZV/1/)